# Google URL Shortener API with python returning error

Tags: python

I'm trying to call the Google URL Shortener API in my python code:

```
def shorternUrl():
        API_KEY = "AIzaSyCvhcU63u5OTnUsdYaCFtDkcutNm6lIEpw"
        apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
        longUrl = "http://www.cnn.com"
        headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
        data = {"longUrl": longUrl}
        h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
        try:
            headers, response = h.request(apiUrl, "POST", urllib.urlencode(data), headers)
            print response

        except Exception, e:
            print "unexpected error %s" % e
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

I'm not using the Google API for Python. Where i'm I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send JSON in a POST, not URL encoded data:

```
import json

# Rest of your code

headers, response = h.request(apiUrl, "POST", json.dumps(data), headers)
```