# Create Google Shortened URLs, Update My CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, url-rewriting, google-api-python-client, google-url-shortener

I've got a list of ~3,000 URLs I'm trying to create Google shortened links of, the idea is this CSV has a list of links and I want my code to output the shortened links in the column next to the original URLs.

I've been trying to modify the code found on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278049/google-url-shortener-api-with-python-returning-error) but I'm not skilled enough to get it to work.

Here's my code (I would not normally post an API key but the original person who asked this already posted it publicly on this site)  :

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Links_Test.csv')
def shorternUrl(my_URL):
    API_KEY = "AIzaSyCvhcU63u5OTnUsdYaCFtDkcutNm6lIEpw"
    apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
    longUrl = my_URL
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    data = {"longUrl": longUrl}
    h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
    headers, response = h.request(apiUrl, "POST", json.dumps(data), headers)
    return response
            

for url in df['URL']:
    x = shorternUrl(url)
    # Then I want it to write x into the column next to the original URL
```

But I only get errors at this point, before I even started figuring out how to write the new URLs to the CSV file.

Here's some sample data:

```
URL
www.apple.com
www.google.com
www.microsoft.com
www.linux.org
```

Comment: I gather that at the moment your shorternUrl function doesn't run at all? ie, even if you try just shorternUrl('www.google.com') you get an error? Looks like a very similar problem to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278049/google-url-shortener-api-with-python-returning-error does that help?

Comment: @JohnFaben, yes, that's the question I link to in my question.  I'm trying to work from that example question to create some code that works for me.  Yes, you are also right that my function doesn't run at all.  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you didnot include the API key in the request. By the way, the `certifi` package allows you to secure a connection to a link. You can get it using `pip install certifi` or `pip urllib3[secure]`.

Here I create my own API key, so you might want to replace it with yours.

```
from urllib3 import PoolManager
import json
import certifi

sampleURL = 'http://www.apple.com'

APIkey = 'AIzaSyD8F41CL3nJBpEf0avqdQELKO2n962VXpA'
APIurl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=' + APIkey
http = PoolManager(cert_reqs = 'CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())

def shortenURL(url):
    data = {'key': APIkey, 'longUrl' : url}
    response = http.request("POST", APIurl, body=json.dumps(data), headers= {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}).data.decode('utf-8')
    r = json.loads(response)
    return (r['id'])
```

The decoding part converts the response object into a string so that we can convert it to a JSON and retrieve data.

From there on, you can store the data into another column and so on.

For the sampleUrl, I got back https(`goo.gl/nujb`) from the function.

Comment: I can't get this to work.  When I try shortenURL(sampleURL) I get a long error message that ends with this "TypeError: urlopen got multiple values for keyword argument 'body'" - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I imported all the libraries as you directed... thank you!

Comment: I think I found the problem.  In Conda, which I using, anything less than urllib3 1.10 will give the error I'm getting.  My Cona won't let me me upgrade to 1.10 where these errors/bugs are resolved.

Comment: My urlib3 version usable with the code is 1.14.1.  This came as default with my installation of PyCharm I guess because when I use the `conda update urllib3` it answers no such package was found. 
In such case, you may want to use `conda install urllib3` command instead.

Comment: This was the best solution, Pyshortner has a time limit of 0.5 sec, that kept failing with my very long list.  This method worked even with a list of over 2,500 URLs to shorten.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshorteners

Example copied from linked page:

```
from pyshorteners import Shortener

url = 'http://www.google.com'
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
shortener = Shortener('Google', api_key=api_key)
print "My short url is {}".format(shortener.short(url))
```